# Batch apex class to update all the account records daily(update field description on account)

Tags: apex

Here is the code

```
 global class TestBatchClass implements Database.Batchable <sobject>{ 
    String query; 
    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
        Query = 'Select id,name,Description from account'; 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    } 
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope){ 
        List<account> accList = new List<account>(); 
        for(account s : scope){
            s.Description = 'Updated in batch apex class'; 
            accList.add(s); 
        } 
        update accList; 
    } 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //comment - finish method can remain blank
    }
}
```

Getting this error :

> Error in line 9: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Account

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get around this error is changing the execute's method signature to this; `global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)`

You can also cast the sObject to an Account object but it's not necessary in this case since you're only updating accounts.